# JSON format: show output as key-pair value per row in Python

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to get decoded data into a Json format. However, when it is printed, it just gives me a whole row of all the data that's behind it:

```
    qrData = qr.data.decode("utf-8")
    qrType = qr.type

    jsonStr = json.dumps(qrData)
 

    # print the QR type and data to the terminal
    print("[INFORMATION] Found {} barcode:\n{}".format(qrType, jsonStr))
```

It gave me the following output:

### Output 1

{"version":1,"insured":{"firstname":"XX","lastname":"XXT"},"vehicle":{"brand":"LEXUS","type":"NX","licensePlate":"ABCDED","country":"XX"},"insurer":{"id":"data",}"

This is just some of the decoded data.

Since I wanted to get the key-pair values in each row (for better readibility), I added the following code:

```
    qrData = qr.data.decode("utf-8")
    qrType = qr.type

    jsonStr = json.dumps(qrData)
    jsonObject = json.loads(qrData)
    pairs = jsonObject.items()

    # print the QR type and data to the terminal
    print("[INFORMATION] Found {} barcode:\n{}".format(qrType, jsonStr))
    for key, value in pairs:
    print(key, ": ", value)
```

It's better, but still doesn't return each key-value:

### Output2

Insurer :  {'id': '123456', 'contractNumber': '0123456789', 'valid_from': '2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z', 'valid_until': '2021-01-30T00:00:00.000Z', 'representativeID': '9876543', 'representativeEmail': 'sample@test.be'}

Is there a way to get a key-value pair per row?

Thank you <3

Comment: To be clear: `qrData` is a *string* in JSON format? And you want to get the parsed JSON data (nested dicts and/or lists) out of it? In your own words, what do you think `json.dumps` is supposed to do? What do you think `json.loads` is supposed to do? Now, what does the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) say?

Comment: If you still can't figure it out, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example , and make sure that you show us *complete* output for a minimal input. The truncated output you're showing doesn't make it clear where the problem is, and clearly doesn't correspond to the `print("[INFORMATION] Found {} barcode:\n{}".format(qrType, jsonStr))` format.

Comment: The qrData is a list containing string type data. I want it to be parsed as a JSON list where each key-value has a row. I need that to later on pull that data from a JSON file.

I think that ´json.dumps()´ converts a Python object (whether it's a list, dictionary, etc) into a JSON format.

Also, not sure what you mean with the complete output :( What I'm getting is a not so readible list in JSON format. It just needs to be 'cleaned up' so it's more readible, if that makes sense?

Comment: " I think that ´json.dumps()´ converts a Python object (whether it's a list, dictionary, etc) into a JSON format. " Right; it takes the parsed JSON and gives you a string. *You want to do the opposite*: you have a string, and you want to create the parsed data.

Comment: I think  you might be a bit confused: "a JSON format" is not actually a thing. Being formatted *as* JSON is a *property* that a string might have: the string either represents JSON data, or it doesn't. Analogously, you don't write "an English"; you write text *in* English.

Comment: I mean yes. You are definitely right! I am quite new to coding. So I'm still trying to figure a lot of stuff out D:

Comment: However, if I understand you correctly, I don't per se have to do the 'json.dumps()' at all, since my qrData already has list containing JSON formatted data?

Comment: I did read the documentation. I just thought it were separate things :/. So, how do I format the output properly, then? Would it be possible to use that output data (without storing it) for further use?

Comment: Not possible to answer as is, because I have no idea what you mean by "properly". Try writing the new code; give it an exact, reproducible, hard-coded test input (write a string with JSON data into the code, instead of using your QR code setup); decide **exactly** what the output should be; and if you don't get it, ask a *new* question showing that reproducible example, the exact actual output, and the exact desired output. (Also: format your output like code.)

Comment: Well, I understand where you're coming from. As you can see from the output, it's just a whole list of key-values. It's not readable. Each key-value should have a different row as output, then be saved as a .json file. I don't know if that clarifies it? However, I'll try and do as you say.

Comment: You should make sure that you understand fully how to use dicts and lists *normally*, because that's what your data *is* after you parse it from JSON. If the question is "how do I display a complex data structure on the command line and make it look readable?", then that is called pretty-printing and you can easily search that term. Alternately, when you write out your JSON, you can look into the formatting options provided by `.dumps` (or `.dump`, if you're writing to file).

Comment: @Kwinten can you post an example of your desired output?